# Can I resume training from checkpoints using the ktrain library?

Tags: python, keras

ktrain is a lightweight wrapper for the deep learning library TensorFlow Keras (and other libraries) to help build, train, and deploy neural networks and other machine learning models. Can I resume training from checkpoints using the ktrain library?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.  This is answered in the ktrain FAQ.  I will copy the answer here:

#### Method 1: Using Predictor API (works for any model)

```py
# save model and Preprocessor instance after partially training
ktrain.get_predictor(model, preproc).save('/tmp/my_predictor')

# reload Predictor and extract model
model = ktrain.load_predictor('/tmp/my_predictor').model

# re-instantiate Learner and continue training
learner = ktrain.get_learner(model, train_data=trn, val_data=val)
learner.fit_onecycle(2e-5, 1)
```

Note that `preproc` here is a *Preprocessor* instance.  If using a data-loading function like `texts_from_csv` or `images_from_folder`, it will be the third return value from the function. Or, if using the [Transformer API](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial-A3-hugging_face_transformers.ipynb) for text classification, it will be the output of invoking `text.Transformer` (i.e., `preproc = text.Transformer('bert-base-uncased', ...)`).

#### Method 2: Using `transformers` library (if training Hugging Face Transformers model)

If the model is a Hugging Face transformers model, you can use `transformers` directly:

```py
# save model using transformers API after partially training
learner.model.save_pretrained('/tmp/my_model')

# reload the model using transformers directly
from transformers import *
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('/tmp/my_model')
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# re-instantiate Learner and continue training
learner = ktrain.get_learner(model, train_data=trn, val_data=val)
learner.fit_onecycle(2e-5, 1)
```

#### Method 3: Using `checkpoint_folder` argument to save model weights

The `checkpoint_folder` argument (e.g., `learner.autofit(1e-4, 4, checkpoint_folder='/tmp/saved_weights')`), saves the weights only of the model after each epoch.
The weights of any epoch can be reloaded into the model using the `model.load_weights` method as you normally would in `tf.Keras`.  You just need to first re-create
the model first.  For instance, if training an NER model, it would work as follows:

```py
# recreate model from scratch
import ktrain
from ktrain import text
model = text.sequence_tagger(...
# load checkpoint weights from 3rd epoch into model
model.load_weights('../models/checkpoints/weights-03.hdf5')
# recreate learner
learner = ktrain.get_learner(model, ...
# continue training here
```

Finally, there is also a `learner.save_model` and `learner.load_model` methods intended for saving and reloading models when training interactively during a single session.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to set the initial epoch number in the learner.fit_onecycle step, so that I don't overwrite checkpoints after starting training again?

Comment: You can simply specify a different checkpoint folder for the second training session upon resuming:  `learner.autofit(1e-4, 4, checkpoint_folder='/tmp/saved_weights_02')`